# Как правильно написать

Tags: орфография

Не хочешь выйти погулять? Или Нехочешь выйти погулять?

Answer (score 1):

Не с глаголами пишется всегда раздельно.Правильно: Не хочешь выйти погулять?

Comment: НЕ с глаголами.